# C# Is there a way to make a shortcut for a directory so that it doesnt have to be user specific?

Tags: c#, string, directory

I'm working on a project that is worked on by multiple different accounts and computers, and would like to know if there's a way to make a directory link so that it wouldn't have to be changed every time someone needs to test it out?

Currently the directory is like this =

```
foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\MyName\OneDrive\files\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\kooditesti\kooditesti\images"))
```

Comment: Use GetFolderPath? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx

Comment: Totally depends on what the link is used for. Is there a reason the path has to be part of a user's profile? If not, there's your fix. If yes, you can use something like [%HOMEPATH%](http://environmentvariables.org/HomePath).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make a shortcut that works on multiple computers by changing the path from an absolute path to a relative path.

I copied the images folder from original visual studio path to the path where I would put the .exe file and the relative path ended up being this:

```
foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(@".\images")
```

and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a bunch of special Folders. These include the user specific ones, but also ones that are shared across Users.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

See ApplicationData vs CommonApplicationData or CommonDocuments vs MyDocuments for examples of a UserSpecific/Cross user folder.

You should avoid the Programm folders, as those tend to be protected by NTFS rights. But the common ones are explicitly there to share so you should never have rights issues on the top level at least.

Comment: Hey, sorry for answering nearly a week late, I have been sick. In this project, the .exe build of the project will go to a completely separate PC, and I need to make the path for the 'images' folder so it works on that specific PC too, but I cant edit the code on that PC. How do I do it from my current PC?

Comment: @Sashkatchewan: Sorry for answering 2 months late. Generally you have a setup that will install the programm and all data it needs (like Pictures) on the places they are needed (like the special Folders).